# kxsmb folder not downloading libs folder iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, file-sharing, smb

I have been trying for quite some time to download the libs folder which contains talloc_stack.h, talloc.h, libsmbclient.h, libsmbclient.a, libtalloc.a, libtdb.a, libwbclient.a, libtevent.a files.But I am not able to download it.Whenever I am doing "RAKE" from within the kxsmb folder in the terminal I get the following errror:

```
Executing tar -zxf samba-4.0.7.tar.gz
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/usr/include/crt_externs.h
/Users/rahul/Downloads/kxsmb-master/Rakefile:52:in `copyIfNotExists'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Could anyone let me know as how can I download it and from where can I download it.

Moreover, can I use this library for for sending image to the windows shared folder from the ios application?

Answer (score 3):

This is my first answer on SO, so please bear with me.

Around the same time the question was asked, I was also facing the same problem. I contacted the developer on twitter as well, but he said that he was not maintaining the library anymore. However thankfully, a kind gentleman has applied a fix and now the library works on Xcode 5:

https://github.com/kolyvan/kxsmb/pull/12

You may also get this error:

> need autoconf 2.53 or later to build samba from GIT

If so, you can download and install autoconf by using this:

curl -OL http://ftpmirror.gnu.org/autoconf/autoconf-2.69.tar.gz
tar -xzf autoconf-2.69.tar.gz 
cd autoconf-2.69
./configure && make && sudo make install